# Затереть свободное пространство на SSD-диске Ubuntu-сервера, без возможности восстановления

Tags: ubuntu, ssd

Арендованный у хостера сервер Ubuntu на SSD 240ГБ. Пользовался им год. Пришло время переезжать. Удалил мои данные и логи.

Теперь стоит задача "затереть" все свободное пространство на диске, чтобы удаленные данные нельзя было восстановить (а в идеале и посмотреть список удаленных файлов тоже).

Есть конечно утилиты типа Shred, которые затирают конкретный файл. Но мне же нужно затереть все свободное пространство на SSD-накопителе, где раньше располагались данные.

Есть идея полностью заполнить диск какими-то ненужными файлами, например, закачать фильмец, и дублировать его до тех пор, пока он полностью не закроет собою все дисковое пространство.

Есть идея написать на PHP скрипт, который создает кучу файлов, заполненных какими-то значениями, пока свободное пространство не закончится.

Но может быть для этой цели есть какая-то подходящая утилита?

Про то, что кому нафик нужны твои данные, можно не писать)

Comment: А диск не виртуальный?

Comment: `cat /dev/urandom > /file.bin` и не надо фильмы качать

Comment: Но вообще, насколько я помню, SSD шифруют данные, и для полного удаления всех данных (вместе с самой убунтой) достаточно сбросить ключ шифрования - без возможности расшифровки данные станут мусором. Так и SSD меньше износится

Comment: Под виндой есть утилита Cipher.exe с ключом /w. Вообще-то она предназначена для шифрации файлов и каталогов. Но вроде бы, начиная с win7, она умеет затирать данные в неиспользуемом дисковом пространстве. Под линуксом тоже что-то похожее должно быть.

Comment: Обычного удаления - вполне достаточно. Мы пытались восстановить удалённые файлы и разделы с кингстонов - вообще по нулям. TRIM отрабатывает на отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь утилитой `secure-delete`. На [это сайте](http://www.bilee.com/x438-26.html) есть подробная информация, как можно прочистить диск несколько раз с помощью неё. Если же вы хотите сделать все другим путем, то можно использовать скрипт на Bash, который будет скачивать файл и удалять его:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 wget https://site.com/file.mp4
 rm file.mp4
done
```

Comment: Мне кажется второй вариант нужно изменить, так как скорее всего file.mp4 будет записываться и тут же удалятся из одного и того же мес та на диске. Наверняка нужно сначала заполнить весь диск, а потом удалять? А secure-delete интересная вещь. Буду пробовать, спасибо

Comment: Хм... Согласен, так будет лучше. Проблема этого скрипта в том, что при загрузки файлов с маленьким весом не всегда происходит удаление. Поэтому советую скачивать файлы размером гигабайт в 5-10. На Хабре [есть стать](https://habr.com/ru/post/357402/) про брутфорс, и там ссылка на архив с 5 Гб.

Comment: а может просто в цикле создавать файл с мусором из какого нибудь потока ввода?

Comment: Я бы просто [создал файл и начал его копировать N количество раз](http://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread2025423.html). Это бы сэкономило мне время и не ломало сильно мозг. А по поводу создания файл с мусором из какого нибудь потока ввода. В принципе все это между собой схоже и имеет одну конечную цель.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zerofile; rm /tmp/zerofile
```

Забивает все свободное место на разделе "нулями"

Если у Вас несколько разделов нужно выполнить для каждого

Comment: Сохранять нули, да ещё и в оперативке вместо SSD - гениально

Comment: Если у Вас раздел /tmp в оперативке сделайте dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/zerofile; rm /home/zerofile

Comment: `Забивает все свободное место на разделе "нулями" ... of=/home/zerofile` -  ну вообще-то не всё, в той же ext4 5% файловой системы по умолчанию будет зарезервированно для нужд суперпользователя, чтобы уменьшить или вообще убрать нужно предварительно выполнить `tune2fs m0 /dev/ssdN` где N ставим нужный нам раздел.

Answer (score 0):

Создаём файл, заполняем нулями без кеширования, удаляем файл:

```
touch file
dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1024K oflag=direct
rm file
```